# How to check whether a partition is mounted by UUID?

Tags: command-line, mount, disk, partitioning

If I have the UUID of a drive partition, how would I go about finding out whether it is mounted or not, using the command line?

Comment: I have UUIDs duplicated on my drives, and this cannot be avoided.

Comment: I believe that you can change the uuid of a partition with `tune2fs`.

Comment: @Joshua, @Arronical Yes, you can change the UUID with `tune2fs -U random /dev/sdxx`. But this won't work for all types of partitions.

Comment: In fact it won't work. The drives must have the same UUID because they're mirrored. Trying to detect by UUID returns duplicate paths rather than only the mirror device.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`lsblk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/lsblk.8) might help. It can print just the UUID and mount point, so, given the UUID, just see if the mount point is not empty:

```
uuid=foo
lsblk -o UUID,MOUNTPOINT | awk -v u="$uuid" '$1 == u {print $2}'
```

So:

```bsh
uuid=foo
mountpoint=$(lsblk -o UUID,MOUNTPOINT | awk -v u="$uuid" '$1 == u {print $2}')
if [[ -n $mountpoint ]]
then
    echo mounted
else
    echo not mounted
fi
```

Since `lsblk` can act on specific devices, you can also do:

```bsh
mountpoint=$(lsblk -o MOUNTPOINT "/dev/disk/by-uuid/$uuid" | awk 'NR==2')
```

With the first method, there won't be an error if that UUID isn't from a currently connected disk. With the second method, `lsblk` error out if `/dev/disk/by-uuid/$uuid` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 18):

```
lsblk -o UUID,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT
```

If you only want one line with your UUID and mountpoint ($UUID represents your UUID):

```
lsblk -o UUID,MOUNTPOINT|grep "$UUID"
```

The mount point will be empty if it is unmounted. Try `lsblk -h` for more options.

Use `awk` to print the result. if `NF` (Number of fields) is more than one it means that it has a mount point:

```
lsblk -o UUID,MOUNTPOINT|grep "$UUID"|awk '{if (NF>1) print $1" is mounted"; else print $1" is unmounted";}'
```

Comment: yes, this ! exactly this ! also can be improved with grep to filter out specific UUID, maybe even parse with awk

Answer (score 9):

If you want the details as from `mount`

```
for uuid in /dev/disk/by-uuid/*; do if [[ "$uuid" =~ .*your-UUID-here.* ]]; then echo $(mount | grep "$(readlink -e "$uuid")") ; fi; done
```

replace `your-UUID-here` with your UUID

more readably:

```
 for uuid in /dev/disk/by-uuid/*; do 
   if [[ "$uuid" =~ .*your-UUID-here.* ]]
     then echo $(mount | grep "$(readlink -e "$uuid")")
   fi
 done
```

output example:

```
/dev/mmcblk1p2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
```

You can just make it check that the string is not null and echo "mounted":

```
for uuid in /dev/disk/by-uuid/*; do if [[ "$uuid" =~ .*your-UUID-here.* ]]; then if [[ $(mount | grep "$(readlink -e "$uuid")") ]]; then echo "mounted"; fi; fi; done
```

but others gave better ways to do that :)

Comment: I like the alternative route +1 :)

Comment: @Arronical very generous of you :D

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu uses `UDisks2` daemon, which polls whole lot of information about file systems, and we can use `udisksctl` and filter its output to find a quick and dirty way to find the info we need:

```
udisksctl dump | python -c 'import sys;lines = [l.strip() for l in sys.stdin if " UUID" in l or " MountPoints:" in l];print "\n".join(lines)'
```

What you see above, basically will print UUIDs of filesystems and their mountpoints. By visual inspection you now can figure out, which UUID is mounted, and which is not.

```
$ udisksctl dump | python -c 'import sys;lines = [l.strip() for l in sys.stdin                                           
> if " UUID" in l or " MountPoints:" in l];print "\n".join(lines)'
MountPoints:        /
UUID:               000b5321-01
MountPoints:
UUID:               bbf23a81-808e-11e4-a445-201a06d7b0e9
MountPoints:
UUID:               bbf23a87-808e-11e4-a445-201a06d7b0e9
MountPoints:
UUID:               bbf23a89-808e-11e4-a445-201a06d7b0e9
MountPoints:
UUID:               bbf23a8f-808e-11e4-a445-201a06d7b0e9
MountPoints:
UUID:               02fe8de2-a408-11e4-8eeb-f0761c8c6df7
MountPoints:        /mnt/HDD
UUID:               53827413-0b7e-4ae6-ae09-1daea529d6a1
```

Answer (score 6):

My solution

- uses only a shell and `procfs`, so no weird command output formatting issues,
- doesn't (re-)scan device UUIDs but uses the kernel cache,
- therefore doesn't require super-user privileges,
- doesn't rely on canonicalised path names but uses (device) file identity.

```sh
my_uuid=...
while IFS=' ' read -r dev mnt remainder; do
  case "$dev" in
  /dev/*)
    if [ "$dev" -ef "/dev/disk/by-uuid/$my_uuid" ]; then
      echo "$my_uuid ($dev) mounted at $mnt"
      break
    fi;;
  esac
done < /proc/mounts
```

Answer (score 5):

Building on the excellent answers I received for this question, I realised that it's much easier to work with device names. To get the device name from UUID:

```
disk_uuid=foo
disk_devname=$(blkid -U "$disk_uuid")
```

Which means I can quickly deduce if it's mounted by grepping the output of `df`:

```
df | grep -q "$disk_devname" && echo "Disk mounted" || echo "Disk not mounted"
```

Or by using the code in [Muru's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/849364/320386), which has the added bonus of telling me where the drive is mounted:

```
mountpoint=$(lsblk -no MOUNTPOINT "$disk_devname")
if [[ -n  "$mountpoint" ]]; then
   echo "Disk is mounted at $mountpoint"
else
   echo "Disk not mounted"
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `df` command to see the mounted file systems and their mount point. Here is an example from my machine ... the partition `sdb3`, on which I have another system installed, is not mounted, so not listed (partitions are re-labeled, that's why names are shown instead of UUIDs) :

```
df
Filesystem                   1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                           8100756        0   8100756   0% /dev
tmpfs                          1625296     9952   1615344   1% /run
/dev/sdb4                     41022688  7074348  31834804  19% /
tmpfs                          8126464    19456   8107008   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                             5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                          8126464        0   8126464   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                       76800    76800         0 100% /snap/ubuntu-core/423
/dev/sdb1                      4186108    12160   4173948   1% /boot/efi
zsc-lxd/containers/uc-1604-1  58620160   516736  58103424   1% /var/lib/lxd/containers/uc-1604-1.zfs
zsc-lxd/containers/uc-1610-1  58637184   533760  58103424   1% /var/lib/lxd/containers/uc-1610-1.zfs
tmpfs                          1625292      124   1625168   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb5                     61796348 10766892  47867344  19% /media/cl/virtual
/dev/sda4                    206293688 13419740 182371804   7% /media/cl/system
/dev/sda3                    206293688 32116600 163674944  17% /media/cl/rescue
/dev/sda2                    206293688  1867604 193923940   1% /media/cl/media
/dev/sda1                    206293688  2539712 193251832   2% /media/cl/data
```

Comment: Can I use partition UUID with `df`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
findmnt --source UUID=uuid
```

If the output is empty, no partition with this `uuid` is mounted, otherwise devicename, mountpoint, filesystem and mount options will be displayed.

Of course, you'll have to replace `uuid` with the actual UUID you want to test.

Comment: I have 5 partitions mounted using `UUID` via `/etc/fstab` and `findmnt --source UUID=uuid` (tried with `sudo` too) did not find any at all. Thanks.

Comment: Oh ok. Yes with an actual `UUID` I did get `/  /dev/sdh1 ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro` as the output. Thanks.

Comment: This might usurp the current answer when I can get on my machine to test. I’ve got a strange feeling I did come across findmnt at some point after asking.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a link named "`the_UUID`" in `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` the partition is mounted. On my Ubuntu 14.04.5 (YMMV):

```
$ ll /dev/disk/by-uuid
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Nov 14 04:30 0123-4567 -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 11 00:25 06ee65d5-26f7-41f3-91ab-3497021a6213 -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 11 00:25 12817b99-9d2b-4357-a4ca-c11eab672a20 -> ../../sdb6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 11 00:25 362254e8-2b99-442d-8ad9-4a348bc08032 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 11 00:25 83a64b80-5a37-4659-b797-221b88ef41f8 -> ../../sdb5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 11 00:25 ff359af0-d996-4949-b27e-f24ce453c48c -> ../../sdc1
```

Comment: Unfortunately my drive which is connected shows up in this list even if not mounted.

Comment: Look for "interesting" messages in `dmesg` and `/var/log/kern.log*`. It sounds like the system is not happy with the filesystem on the partition, and can't mount it. One possible cause is Windows hibernation.

Comment: I think I may have been confusing, the drive mounts and unmounts cleanly. It's just that while it's not mounted, but is connected and switched on, it shows up in the `/dev/disks/by-uuid/` directory.

Comment: Nope, `/dev/disk/by-uuid` and its counterparts holds all UUIDs/IDs/labels of connected devices known to udev regardless of their mount state.